# Jhipster Multi-tenancy with Hibernate Second Level Caching

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, ehcache, jhipster

I've been attempting to turn my JHipster generated application into a multi-tenancy app using this - http://jannatconsulting.com/blog/?p=41 blog post as a base.

I've run into a problem with second level caching. Spring boot appears to correctly detect and set up:

> **DatabaseConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JpaProperties.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "masterEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "masterTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.quadrimular.nts.helium.repository.master"})
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("com.quadrimular.nts.helium.repository.search")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Inject
    private DataSourceProperties datasourceProperties;

    @Inject
    private JHipsterProperties jhipsterProperties;

    @Inject
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    @ConditionalOnExpression("#{!environment.acceptsProfiles('cloud') && !environment.acceptsProfiles('heroku')}")
    public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties, JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        log.debug("Configuring Master Datasource");
        if (dataSourceProperties.getUrl() == null) {
            log.error("Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application" +
                    " cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
                Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

            throw new ApplicationContextException("Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
        }
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("url", dataSourceProperties.getUrl());
        if (dataSourceProperties.getUsername() != null) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("user", dataSourceProperties.getUsername());
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("user", ""); // HikariCP doesn't allow null user
        }
        if (dataSourceProperties.getPassword() != null) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("password", dataSourceProperties.getPassword());
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("password", ""); // HikariCP doesn't allow null password
        }

        //MySQL optimizations, see https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration
        if ("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource".equals(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", jHipsterProperties.getDatasource().isCachePrepStmts());
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", jHipsterProperties.getDatasource().getPrepStmtCacheSize());
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", jHipsterProperties.getDatasource().getPrepStmtCacheSqlLimit());
        }
        if (metricRegistry != null) {
            config.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
        }
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean(name = "masterEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource(datasourceProperties, jhipsterProperties));
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.quadrimular.nts.helium.domain.master"});
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalJpaProperties());

        em.setPersistenceUnitName("master");

        return em;
    }

    private Properties additionalJpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(dataSource).entrySet()) {
            properties.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return properties;
    }
    @Bean(name = "masterTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory masterEntityManager){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(masterEntityManager);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

When spring tries to configure:

> **MultiTenancyJPAConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JpaProperties.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "tenantEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "tenantTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.quadrimular.nts.helium.repository.tenant"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MultiTenancyJpaConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "tenantEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                           MultiTenantConnectionProvider connectionProvider,
                                                           CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver tenantResolver) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emfBean.setPackagesToScan("com.quadrimular.nts.helium.domain.tenant");
        emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, connectionProvider);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, tenantResolver);
        properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");

        emfBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return emfBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "tenantTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory tenantEntityManager){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(tenantEntityManager);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

I'm getting this in my trace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
```

I have all the required properties defined in my application-dev.yml

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
hibernate.generate_statistics: true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
```

It appears that it's being read and used correctly by spring boot for my DatabaseConfiguration.java. I can't work out why it's not detecting the property file. If I try to disable the cache by setting:

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
```

DatabaseConfiguration.java detects and behaves accordingly however MultiTenancyJPAConfiguration.java still throws the same exception.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Might sound stupid but as I see you tried with dev profile, have you tried with prod profile? Some classes have conditional annotations based on profile.

Comment: @Gaël Had already tried running as fast profile to disable the cache with no luck. Have just tried running using the prod profile, still gettting the exact same exception.

Comment: The link provided in the question is broken (404) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is to actually set the jpa property values on the entity manager**. I'm not sure how I overlooked this; I thought that somehow they were already set.

Firstly I injected the main datasource and the jpa properties object provided by spring boot if I'm not mistaken.

> **MultiTenancyJPAConfiguration.java**

```
@Inject
private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

@Inject
private DataSource dataSource;
```

I then set the values using the same method used in **DatabaseConfiguration.java**

> **MultiTenancyJPAConfiguration.java**

```
    @Bean(name = "tenantEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                           MultiTenantConnectionProvider connectionProvider,
                                                           CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver tenantResolver) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emfBean.setPackagesToScan("com.quadrimular.nts.helium.domain.tenant");
        emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, connectionProvider);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, tenantResolver);
        properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");

        emfBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        emfBean.setJpaProperties(additionalJpaProperties());

        return emfBean;
    }

    private Properties additionalJpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(dataSource).entrySet()) {
            properties.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return properties;
    }
```

Using the method additionalJpaProperties() to get all the hibernate jpa properties for my main datasource. I then set the hibernate property map properties after the hard coded ones. Clearly not the cleanest solution I plan to set all jpa values from the .yml file.